# Magento: Upgrade modules, Compile code, Deploy static content, Flush cache

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, setup-upgrade, setup-di-compile, upgradeschema

I am running this gist after changing anything in module code. I need feedback for improving this gist & Magento 2 development.

https://gist.github.com/enishant/211212beeadff49aba00c0622a0f33ab

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento
php=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.29/bin/php
MEMORY_LIMIT=" -dmemory_limit=-1 "
$php $MEMORY_LIMIT bin/magento setup:upgrade
$php $MEMORY_LIMIT bin/magento setup:di:compile
$php $MEMORY_LIMIT bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
$php $MEMORY_LIMIT bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1):

In developer mode deploy static and compilation are not necessary so it's not usefull to have them. In production mode these operations are probably done by your deployment tools (jenkins, capistrano , etc )

Also please try to update your question with the code and not just providing a link that can stop working any time.